# How to pass data from function to angular controller scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-file-upload

I stuck at this problem for days.
I use [angular file upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) to upload image.
I can upload the image to the server, and I can get the response image url from the server back.

But I can't get the response image url into my controller's `$scope`, therefore I cannot preserve the url to the outer controller.

The following is part of my code.

```
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader',  function ($scope, FileUploader) {
    $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/upload',
    });
    $scope.imgurl = {};   // I want to put the response url here. 

    $scope.answer = function (answer) {
        $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };


    $scope.uploader.onCompleteItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        console.info(response.name); // here I can get the response url

    };

}]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the value,

```
 $scope.uploader.onCompleteItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        console.info(response.name); // here I can get the response url
         $scope.imgurl = response.name; 
};
```